# How do I print individuals fields in block.html.twig when is a node in a block?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

How do I print individuals fields in block.html.twig when is a node in a block?

The template is working fine. I can hard code some random text and it is displayed. I just can't display the field values.

I have already tried

```
{{content.my_field.0}}
{{content.my_field[0]}}
{{node.my_field.0.value}}
{{ content.my_field }}
```

But, after clear the cache doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried `{{ content.my_field }}`?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried {{ content.my_field }} and also I always clear the cache @NoSssweat

Comment: What do you mean by `when is a node in a block`?

Comment: `doesnt work` Are you getting an error?

Comment: @leymannx is a custom block, a node in a Block

Comment: @NoSssweat not, is not display the field values

Comment: Does it show up when you just do `{{ content }}` ?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, works perfectly when I use {{content}} but not when I try to display individuals fields

Comment: And you know Devel's submodule Kint that lets you put `{{ kint() }}` in the template to inspect onpage what variables/objects are available? And have tried that already? I still don't get though where the node actually comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "node" in the twig-variables of your block. I.e. you can do this in a template_preprocess hook like so:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_myBlock(&$variables) {
  $variables['node'] = Node:load(50);
}
```

Then you can access the "node" in your template like `{{node.my_field.value}}`.

The hard part is to find which node to load in the preprocess function :-)

Comment: Better way would be to have a block plugin with a specialized template. Then set the "node" in the build() function of your block plugin.

Comment: Better a custom block and then get the current node from context. https://gist.github.com/dsnopek/b4e0bc096b216d63a96d17559484dc51